# Helm iterate over keys

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to iterate over list of secrets in my values files and mount it as env variables on the pods but having hard time with it.

The helm template command which spits the sample template lists the keys & value as I expect it to be but when i deploy only the "name" key gets mounted on the pods but nothing after that like the valuefrom and secretkeyref. Really appreciate any help on this :)

```
**DEPLOYMENT YAML**
{{- if $root.Values.secrets }}
  {{- range $secrets := $root.Values.secrets }}
    {{- range $data := $secrets.data }}
          - name: {{ $data.name }}
            valuefrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ $secrets.name }}
                key: {{ $data.name }}
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

```
secrets:
  - name: aws-secrets
    data:
      - key: "secret1"
        name: DATABASE_HOST
      - key: "secret2"
        name: DATABASE_NAME
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fat fingered should be "valueFrom".